# How do I permanently store a userName from a one time called Activity in Android(Java)?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I hope you have an excellent day.

1: Now, I have a Login activity which is called only for **once** after the app has been installed and it asks for only the userName.

2: I store this userName in SharedPreferences and then send the value of this SharedPreference by an intent to my home activity.

3: Now, in my home activity I store this Username received by the intent into SharedPreference and display them, fair enough and everything works fine for only the first run of the app after the install.

4: When I close the app and re-run it then the userName value is set to **null** in spite of the fact that the login activity was never called so, as far as my understanding goes the SharedPreference in the home activity should not be updated to null if the Login activity is never called right? so why does it happens that my SharedPreference value becomes **null** on my second run?

5: **I need a way so as my userName value in the home-activity never gets updated on the second run
of the app**, also I want to be enlightened if my concepts are wrong.

6: In case those 5 points were not clear enough, ** I want to send data from an activity which is called for only once to one normal activity and store it permanently without any updation.**

7: A similar example would be **ShareIt** app which ask for userName once and it's stored permanently in the next activity.

Comment: Please share your code how you store and read value in and from shared pref.

Comment: Actually, I solved it check my answer and then maybe better versions to do it may come

Comment: @ShivanshSharma I would still share your code if you don't mind so that future users can get an idea of what you're doing. Also; I suggest using text files to store bits of information like that - that way, they don't get deleted if someone accidentally clears their Shared Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve the issue is that I simply created another SharedPreference in my home-activity(read the question for clarity) and checked if my **first SharedPreference** was not null i.e only the case of the first run, then copy the value to the second SharedPreference and display it's value.
Here's a code snippet.

```
 if(!preferences1.getString("USERNAME","empty").equals("empty")){
            preferences2.edit().putString("UN",preferences1.getString("USERNAME","empty")).apply();
        }
```

Instead of null, I simply used the string "empty" but one can choose null as well.